# AsyncTask, inner classes and Buttons states

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask, nested-class

For a musical application (a sequencer), I have a few buttons

```
static ArrayList<Button> Buttonlist = new  ArrayList<Button>(); 

    Buttonlist.add(0,(Button) findViewById(R.id.case_kick1));
    Buttonlist.add(1,(Button) findViewById(R.id.case_kick2));
    Buttonlist.add(2,(Button) findViewById(R.id.case_kick3));
    Buttonlist.add(3,(Button) findViewById(R.id.case_kick4));
    Buttonlist.add(4,(Button) findViewById(R.id.case_kick5));
    Buttonlist.add(5,(Button) findViewById(R.id.case_kick6));
    Buttonlist.add(6,(Button) findViewById(R.id.case_kick7));
    Buttonlist.add(7,(Button) findViewById(R.id.case_kick8));
```

that I activate through onClickListeners with for example

```
Buttonlist.get(0).setActivated(true);
```

I played the activated sound via a loop and ifs :

```
if (Buttonlist.get(k).isActivated()) {mSoundManager.playSound(1); Thread.sleep(250);}
```

The app played fine but I couldn't access the play/pause button when it was playing : I searched and found out about AsyncTasks.

I have a nested class PlayPause :

```
class PlayPause extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Button>,Integer,Void>
```

in which I have this :

```
protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<Button>... params) {

    for(int k=0;k<8;k++)
    {
    boolean isPlayed = false;

    if (Buttonlist.get(k).isActivated()) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(1); 
    isPlayed = true;
    try {Thread.sleep(250);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();}}

    if(!isPlayed){
    try {Thread.sleep(250);}
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

   }
 return null;

}
```

I launch it via

```
   Play.setOnClickListener(new PlayClickListener());
```

with PlayClickListener :

```
public class PlayClickListener implements OnClickListener {

private Tutorial acti;


public PlayClickListener(){
    super();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if(Tutorial.play==0){
        Tutorial.play=1;
        Tutorial.Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.action_down);
        acti = new Tutorial();
    Tutorial.PlayPause myPlayPause = acti.new PlayPause();
    myPlayPause.execute(Tutorial.Buttonlist);
    }
    else
    {
    Tutorial.play=0;
    Tutorial.myPlayPause.cancel(true);
    Tutorial.Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.action);
    }
}

 }
```

But it doesn't work. when I click on buttons and I touch Play/Pause, I have this :

```
07-02 11:06:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7883): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-02 11:06:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7883): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 11:06:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7883):     at com.Tutorial.Tutorial$PlayPause.doInBackground(Tutorial.java:603)
07-02 11:06:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7883):     at com.Tutorial.Tutorial$PlayPause.doInBackground(Tutorial.java:1)
```

And I don't know how to get rid of this error. Obviously, the Asynctask doesn't find the Buttonlist activated status, even if the list is static. I don't know how to access these buttons' states, isPressed doesn't work either.

Thanks for reading and helping me !

Comment: Where is line 603 in the code?

Comment: line 603 is `if (Buttonlist.get(k).isActivated()) {mSoundManager.playSound(1); Thread.sleep(250);}`

Comment: I don't think this is the problem but you seem to be passing in the ArrayList as a parameter and then just using the original reference instead of the parameter.

Comment: The ArrayList<Button> params that you are passing in the doInBackground method where is it actually used? I can't find it in your code. Because I guess there is something wrong there.

Comment: @10s : But even when I use it (see the answer below), I get a nullPointerException because the if condition with isActivated doesn't work.

Comment: ok, passing the reference of a static parameter is wrong by its core. You should make the changes to the same static variable, including all the appropriate locks and stuff. So you are sure that you change the setActivated property of the button before you call the AsyncTask, correct?

Comment: I have for each button : 

`Buttonlist.get(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    int on =0;      
    public void onClick(View v) {
     
          
  
     if(on==0){
              Buttonlist.get(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bouton_down);
                 Buttonlist.get(1).setActivated(true);
                 on=1;
    }
    else{
              Buttonlist.get(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bouton);
              Buttonlist.get(1).setActivated(false);
              on=0;
    }`


The AsyncTask is called after the pattern of sound is done.

Comment: Man I am totally curious why this doesn't work. ok try something in the debugger and post the results: debug line in the if statement and "watch" the 2 arrays of the buttons, the one inside async task and the static variable on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `ButtonList` from the `AsyncTask`, you must refer to it by the name of the parameter passed into the `AsyncTask`, in this case `params`. With an `AsyncTask`, the params passed in is always an `Array` of the type specified in between the `<....>` and to access it (if you are only passing in one array list) would be like this...

`ArrayList<Button> Buttonlist = params[0];`

You can then access it from your `AsyncTask`. Although I would suggest giving it a different name just incase there is any conflicts.

To clarify, you can pass as many objects as you want into an `AsyncTask`, comma seperated, and the system takes care of packaging them into an Array which it hands to the `AsyncTask`. In your case you a passing in only one array list, so the async task is being handed an array with only one object in it. So you would look in the first space of the params array, hence `params[0]`

This is all a little confusing, but it's because the system is managing a thread pool for you and alot of the implementation is hidden.

Comment: I did what you said : `ArrayList<Button> Kick = params[0];`


And in debug mode, I saw that the button are there with the correct ID, the Kick ArrayList isn't empty. But isPlayed is always false. The isActivated method seems to lead nowhere, hence the nullPointerException.

Is `if (Kick.get(k).isActivated())` the right way to do it ? 

I tried to extend the Button class to include an int state but I had then the error **stateButton cannot be cast as a Button**.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve with all this. Why are you passing in the buttons? When you start the AsyncTask, you are handing it static data, so it's going to loop 8 times, possibly play each sound once (if it's activated) then return. If this is the behaviour you want, why not work out the state of each button on the main thread, then pass an array of corresponding booleans into asyncTask?

Comment: Buttons are UI elements, and you shouldn't ever try and access any UI elements from a background thread (async task has special synchronized methods to communicating back to the UI onProgressUpdate()). Also remember that if you are planning on repeating this process, you will need to create a new instance of the AsyncTask class each time (reusing an asyncTask instance will crash your program too)

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to this : 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q8CMAOdRWQ

I use asynctask because I give the ability to loop those 8 times with a while(repeat==true){play} and when I'm doing it on the main thread, the sounds are looping but I can't stop the while loop since the app is waiting for the loop to finish...

But I don't know if this is the right way to do it. Doing this will create a new Asynctask every second and kill the precedent one...

I will try to pass an array of corresponding booleans, it's a good idea.

Comment: could you paste up your whole class? In general I've found that using an AsyncTask for this kind of thing will turn out to be more hassle than it's worth. You might consider kicking off threads manually, using Runnables and spawning a new thread for each sound? If you can post up the whole class somewhere that would help me understand it a bit better

Comment: I used Threads and a runnable while using arrays of booleans, and it works perfectly ! thanks !

Comment: Well perfectly ... The timing isn't sharp, but I've read that android's sound libraries weren't very reliable...

Comment: great! This stuff can be a real headache sometimes